# automatic conversion of a full product name into a "searchable" product name

Tags: data-mining

given product names which are retrieved from an external source, I am trying to search for these products on social media. The process should be automated. I am facing a problem that the full names of products are not used on social media.

E.g. *Samsung Galaxy S3 i9300 16GB* is the full name which is retrieved, but noone uses it. Everyone uses  a shorten version like *Samsung Galaxy S3* or *Galaxy S3*.

Or *Casio G-Shock GA-110NM-2 Sports Stylish Watch - Blue* is rather used as *G-Shock GA-110NM-2*.

Would you have an idea how to automatise or reasonably semi-automatise this process?

Thank you very much,
Adam

Comment: Lol, I worked on a similar project over last summer. A very simple solution is to generate [n-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) for suitable `n` from your product names and search for all n-grams on social media, returning only the n-gram that returns the most results on social media. [Here's a Python n-gram library](https://pythonhosted.org/ngram/ngram.html).

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It is an interesting idea. Btw. did you deal somehow with a problem that e.g. n-gram with n=3 of _Samsung Galaxy S3 i9300 16GB_ might be _Samsung Galaxy 16GB_. I assume that this n-gram would end up returning the most results as it would include also posts from Samsung Galaxy 3,4,5,6,7.

Comment: In my previous comment, I wrongly interpreted n-grams as permutations.

Comment: I would imagine the right way to handle potential issues like that is to then explicitly force S3 to be included in the n-gram or filter out posts that mention competing products.